# confused about how site module works in python

Tags: python, site-packages

Documentation of `site module`([Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site)) says this

> This module is automatically imported during initialization. The
>   automatic import can be suppressed using the interpreter’s -S option.

So, according to that `site` module should already be loaded. But, when i try to use `site` or even check `globals` , i don't see site anywhere. Why is that?

Comment: I see it with `import sys` and then `"site" in sys.modules` that lists imported modules.

Comment: `>>> [mod for mod in sys.modules if 'site' in mod]`gives
`['site', '_sitebuiltins']`

Comment: and `import site` works but all this does not answer your question.

Comment: It also appears right away in `sys,modules.keys()` without manual import.